# How to separate words from sentences and to do average? Text mining with R

Tags: r, text, machine-learning, text-mining, text-analysis

I have list of hundreds of email subject lines. For each of the subject line, I have the email open rate (opened email/delivered email) value.
For example:
[list of subject lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzDZ.jpg)

I want to understand if there is influence for some words on the average open rate.

For example, maybe if I’ll write in the email subject line the word “Thanks”, the email open rate will be higher.

If I understand correctly the logical steps, I need to build list of all the words that are in the emails subject line, and for each word to do average between all the subject lines.
For example:
[average per word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1Mx.jpg)

Can someone help me to do it with R? I think there is text mining packages that can help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have a look at the `tm` package

Comment: Thanks Mhairi McNeill, something more specific?

Comment: Sorry for the brevity - it's a big topic! Search for 'text mining in R' or 'R tm' and you should find a tutorial

Comment: Actually (shameless plug for myself) I made a tutorial and video in my old job: https://deltadna.com/blog/text-mining-in-r-for-term-frequency/

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a logistic regression with words from the header as the independent variable. Or if the number of words were small or if you were able to group the words, perhaps a multiple regression.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Thanks.

Comment: Create a csv table, wherein column 0 contains the open rate. columns 2 onwards contains the words which you wish to analyse with the frequency the word appears in the header or 0 if it does not. Now try the following commands, all_data <- read.table("datass.csv",header = TRUE, sep=",");
    dependent_variable <- matrix(datas[,1]);
    model <- glm(dependent_variable ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train);
This should generate a table with coefficients detailing the relationship between open rate and the occurrence of a word.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your major problem is splitting the strings containing the email titles.

You can use the `strsplit()` function to do so. 
For example :
`yourstring <- "A string, full of punctuation ! And spaces !"
tosplit <- c(" ", "!", ...) 
matrix <- strsplit(yourstring, tosplit)`

Then I guess you can use a loop to put each word of the matrix in a column of your data-set.
(You should change all the words to lowercase too, if you wish : `tolower(matrix)`)

After that, surely a `table()` or a `summary()` of your data-frame will help you to visualize better.

As for the text-mining packages, I'm not aware of any but I reckon there are some.

Answer (score 0):

So after i saw all the comments, i try to organize it to one piece of code. Works for me.
Thank you all.

```
SentencesVector ### vector with the sentences 
AveragesVector ###  vector with the averages open rate
SubjectLineTable = data.frame(AveragesVector,SentencesVector)

library(tm)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(SentencesVector))
myTdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
temp <- inspect(myTdm)
FreqMat <- data.frame(ST = rownames(temp), Freq = rowSums(temp))
row.names(FreqMat) <- NULL

localAverage = 0
counter = 0
averageTable = 0

for(i in 1:nrow(FreqMat)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(SubjectLineTable)){
       if(grepl(FreqMat[i,1],SubjectLineTable[j,2])){
          counter = counter+1
          localAverage[counter] = SubjectLineTable[j,1]}
    }
  averageTable[i] = mean(localAverage)
  localAverage = 0
  counter = 0
}
FreqMat$means = averageTable
FreqMat

fit = step(glm(means~.,data = FreqMat))
summary(fit)
```